# how to make category in category in category

Tags: wordpress

i have problem in wordpress

i need way to make category in catgory in category in category

example

i have category have name bmw have sub catgory xll in xll catgory 1999 in catgory 1999 have sub catgory parts and others catgory like engine , etc

so we have 4 level catgory

how we do that this is my code

```
<?php

                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'taxonomy'=>'brand_category',
                        'parent' => 0
                    );
                    $categories = get_categories( $args );
                    if($categories->parent > 0){ ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id );?>"><?php echo  $category->name ;?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php  $queried_object = get_queried_object();
                                  $term_ids = $queried_object->term_id;
                                  $term_id = $term_ids;
                                  $taxonomy_name = 'brand_category';
                                  $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name, $parent = $term->parent);
                                  $parent = $term->parent;

                                  ?>
                    <?php foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
                                      $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                                      echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
                                  }?>
                    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: hey , my problem i need 4 level category that is simple

Comment: Do you mean that, you want to query categories with their child categories up to 4 level?

Comment: yes that i need

Comment: Check this thread. It will give you some idea to do what you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656826/wordpress-nested-list-of-categories-subcategories

Comment: thanks but it only 2 level category how if we need more like 4 category

Comment: any help guys ??!!